# zk - Empty column for a scrollbar on a grid

Tags: zk

It's my first time working on zk and i have this guideline.

> There is an empty column on the far right that fills the empty space between the last column and the right edge of the Grid. When the content is loaded the scroll should appear inside that column.

Is it possible to do this? do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/22h1jqu/13-scroll-grid-to-last-row-after-render) if your run it under zk 7.0.2 or 7.0.3?

If link dies this is the code :

```
<zk>
    <window border="normal" title="hello" >
        <grid height="300px">
            <columns>
                <column label="Chat Message" sort="auto" />
                <column label="By" sort="auto" />
            </columns>
            <rows id="rows">
                <zk forEach="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10">
                    <row>
                        <label value="Message ${each}"/>
                        <label value="By User ${each}"/>
                    </row>
                </zk>
            </rows>
        </grid>
    </window>
</zk>
```